# linker command failed with exit code 1, framework and library errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4, xcode5

I recently received the source code for an app built in 2013 (last year).  However, when I try to run it, I receive 3 warnings:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/chesteryeum/iOS/appName/appName_chester'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/chesteryeum/iOS/appName/appName_chester/ZBarSDK'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/chesteryeum/iOS/appName/appName_chester'
```

And one error

```
ld: library not found for -lzbar
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

A few extra points:

1) chesteryeum is the name of the previous developer, and /Users/chesteryeum is not on my computer, or locatable in finder.

2) Other Linker Flags is empty, Framework Search Paths is empty, Library Search Paths is empty.

3) It seems like the app was built in xCode 4, whereas I am using xCode 5.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks in advance,

-Nick

Update:  The 3 warnings have been fixed by the answer by Droppy, but the error still remains.

Comment: Is the app you're working on called "Gluten247"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the *library search path* is hardcoded to the previous developers locations on their disk.  This is obviously bad.

What you need to do is create a relative directory structure and then set the *library/header search paths* to use something like `$(SRCROOT)/ZBarSDK`.

Comment: How would I go about creating a relative directory structure?

Comment: This worked for all 3 warnings, but it didn't fix the error.  Do you have any more ideas about what the error is?

Comment: It depends on the directory structure. Please add it to your question along with the search path values you are using. Also why did you accept the answer if it's not working?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by directory structure, do you mean the way that the groups are organized?  And I accepted it because it worked for a significant part of the problem, and will likely fix the remainder once I understand how to do what you suggest.

Comment: @Peperononew What is mean is where the SDK is relative to the app's Xcode project.  It could be within the project directory (`$SRCROOT`) or as a sibling (`$(SRCROOT)/../`), or anywhere really, but you must maintain a relative relationship in order for `$SRCROOT` to work.